# retrieving files from browser cache

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, caching

I accidentally deleted a PDF file from both my web server and my development machine.  I want to check my browser's cache to see if there's a copy of it in there. Where do I look?  I use both Firefox and Internet Explorer, so I'd like to search both of their caches.

Answer (score 2):

Nirsoft has free cache viewers for [Firefox](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mozilla_cache_viewer.html) and for [Internet Explorer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ie_cache_viewer.html).

BTW, this would be a good time to think about using version control for your work ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The PDF seems to not be in the web broswer cache. I think you are looking in the caches because you read your PDF with a PDF reader included in your web broswer. In Linux there exist a directory cache for acroread (Adobe). This should be the same for Windows.

Comment: PDFs read with Acrobat are generally saved in the %TMP% directory under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

in firefox: navigate to `about:cache`

Comment: If I do this, it just gives me a link to the original location. How do I get the cached version of the file?

Comment: just click the key and then on the key once more (it looks like the normal URL but FF takes it from the cache). You can also change to offline mode (File -> Work Offline)